# Ubuntu 12.10: start applications in certain workspace on bootup

Tags: 12.10, startup, workspaces

I am looking for an application or script etc that would allow me to run my start up applications in different workspaces.
I currently have 8 workspaces and 6 programs I always have start up, however it becomes a real pain to move each program to there respective workspaces each boot up.

I have found a few ways of doing this but nothing speaks of Ubuntu 12.04/10 with unity.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install Compiz manager, click on Place windows button, click Fixed window placement and on the bottom there is Window with fixed viewport. Add a new one and set the position where exactly you want it. For progam, you can just grab it.